# Dynamically getting the keys from a nested object

Tags: typescript

I have a 3 level object will be generated similar to how openApi works, at project install time, or as a first step at compile time.

```
const translations = {
    26: {
        ro: {
            test: 'test',
        },
        en: {
            lorem: 'test',
            test: 'test',
        },
    },
    32: {
        en: {
            test: 'test',
        },
    },
};
```

The structure represents:

translations -> moduleID (dynamic) -> language (dynamic based on some other settings) ->
dynamic based on moduleID

Later in my code we want:

```
const lang = 'en' 
function getModuleTranslations<K extends keyof typeof x, T extends keyof typeof x[K][lang]>(mid: K): (key: T) => any {
        return (key) => x[mid][lang][key];
    }

....

const translate = getModuleTranslations(32);  // We want type checking & autocomplete here
const testString = translate('test'); // We want type checking & autocomplete here as well based on the above getModuleTranslations(32)
```

In our case, the language param will be given by the class, at runtime.

I found multiple ways of accessing nested properties this way (translations, '32.en.test'), but this isn't what we want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would it work for you to add an intermediate function call to go from the module to the language within that module? If so, this will work:

```js
const translations = {
  26: {
    ro: {
      test: "test",
    },
    en: {
      lorem: "test",
      test: "test",
    },
  },
  32: {
    en: {
      test: "test",
    },
  },
} as const;

function getModuleTranslations(mid: keyof typeof translations) {
  const m = translations[mid];

  return (lang: keyof typeof m) => {
    const l = m[lang];

    return (key: keyof typeof l) => {
      return l[key];
    };
  };
}

const getLanguageTranslations = getModuleTranslations(32);
const translate = getLanguageTranslations("en");

const translateTest = translate("test");
console.log(translateTest);

// Argument of type '"not there"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"test"'.
const translateNotThere = translate("not there");
console.log(translateNotThere);
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFBOBDSAbRUCW4IwLwwG8AoGGAJgDYAuQk0meEG4++qAU2hoCIPpuANHVIBfIa3Zhmw+ihDx2AWx58ogmaVUrOa8fTF0DpAMxlpEqbVaad2-ntF6DImIhyhIUANxEiAMwBXMGBMcBgAc3YoAFkQABMAlHYAFSRUdCxIAApFDDiaAGt2AE8QPzhigAd2Mrg0iDRQyABKKxgPaBhFPDrkBozsAG1cuIBdHzoFKAD4MBgstDBwwpLaqCqa8sVW3AA+NtIO2BQexUHF8PHfVimZuayi4pXS8vXq2pQd-ZZrW9mYFCDR5XVgiHyiHwiXxHCJRAAyyHCAUQkVSfUamRw+EiMXiiRS9Qx2CypmaPhhCHR6HYPRxCKWyNRhIG2W4km4ZOh2FglPSHGSOh6vP6HCyvB0HPJ2BASQAdHJwllhY0UjpOUQAPQamAAQXgSMUklgaw2MAA5NwwCAeQALdgKbhmmAYHBW2BuCAYcJgRAAIyScBAMEqiCQho48BgJuq5vF-DNsqIFOZHAActbknaFEKU+wxW64Fn2JKk9K5Qqlbn01BM-b2GSgA)

Comment: Thank you, yes, this seems to be a solution, although I don't get autocomplete, but it's fine for the moment